# iOS : localization issue on iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, translation

My app is made to work for dutch & french people.

On iOS 10, when a french starts the app, the language is french. When a dutch starts the app, the language is NL. For iOS 10, all is working fine.

But, for iOS 9, a dutch who starts the app, the language is french, not NL.
I don't understand why, it's working perfectly in iOS10, I don't found what is specific to iOS 9.

Any idea ?

EDIT : I'm using the option "Localization" (in the "File inspector") of the file "Localizable.strings" created. With that, I check NL language, and I've two "Localizable.strings", one for french, one for NL.

I did the same thing for the storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little stupid sometimes....

I didn't change the country on the simulator. It was US, so I had "nl-US" in my app, so, the app showed the base language (french).

Problem solved...